# Create Controller using artisan - InvalidArgumentException

Tags: laravel-4

I am new to laravel.

I have copied command to create controller from a book and I am trying to run that command:

```
php artisan Usercontroller:make users
```

I am getting error:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  There are no commands defined in the "Usercontroller" namespace.
  Did you mean this?
      controller
```

Current working directory is project directory:

```
C:\wamp\www\laravel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in commmand,

you should use

```
php artisan controller:make users
```

Hope  this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Command should be

```
php artisan controller:make users
```